# c# Api Controller routing ignores Action

Tags: api, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following Api class and method:

```
public class LicenceController : ApiController
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Checks whether the person has a verified licence
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="forename">Person's first name</param>
        /// <param name="surname">Person's second name</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public bool Verify(string forename, string surname)
        {
            return true;
        }
}
```

And the following WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "Verify",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{forename}/{surname}/{licence}"
            );

        }
```

When I attempt to call my api method in the browser with the following URL then it works fine:
http://localhost/api/Licence/Verify?forename=Sam&surname=Jones

But if I enter another action name instead of Verify then it also routes to the same method...ideally I'd like it to error as the action doesn't exist. So if i enter:
http://localhost/api/Licence/ThisActionDoesntExist?forename=Sam&surname=Jones
Then that last URL should error...but its resolving to the same place. Have an error my routing configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routing in MVC is dependant on the order in which you specify the rules in your configuration. In this case, the *second* URL is picked up by the *first* rule and because you don't specify the action to call, it tries to make a best guess which in this case is the only possible action that allows a GET request.

Comment: Bingo! I have added an {action} into the route template of the first rule and that seems to be working now :)
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );